# How to find the common pairs of strings between text files irrespective of their pair order?

Tags: python

I have 3 text files in the following format:

Text File 1:

```
A1, B1, 80
A2, B1, 76
A1, B2, 97
A2, B2, 73
```

Text File 2:

```
B1, A2, 0.56
A1, B2, 0.68
B1, A1, 0.89
B2, A2, 0.63
C1, D2, 0.89
D2, E3, 0.63
```

Text File 3:

```
B1, A1, 1102
B1, A2, 1405
B2, A1, 2113
B2, A2, 1448
C3, D1, 3569
E2, C3, 7852
```

The output should be all pairs of first two strings that are common between the text files along with their values irrespective of the pair order. For example, the output, in this case, would be:

```
A1, B1, 80, 0.89, 1102
A2, B1, 76, 0.56, 1405
A1, B2, 97, 0.68, 2113
A2, B2, 73, 0.63, 1448
```

I tried the following code but not getting the expected output correctly.

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
for fileName in ["Text File 1.txt","Text File 2.txt", "Text File 3.txt"]:
    with open(fileName,'r') as file1:
        for line in file1:
            col1,col2,value = line.split(",")
            data[(col1,col2)].append(float(value))

with open("Common_Pairs.txt","w") as output:
    for (col1,col2),values in data.items():
        if len(values) < 3: continue           
        result = [x for x in values] 
        output.write(f"{col1},{col2}, {result}\n")
```

Comment: The problem looks to be the order of the tuple in your `data` dictionary - the `value`s are only combined if the order matches that already in the dict. For example, `("A1", "B1")` will not be grouped with `("B1", "A1")`. The duplicate should address your question.

Comment: Sort the keys, then reassign: 1) key = sorted([col1.strip(), col2.strip()], key=lambda s: list(s)[0])   2) col1, col2 = key

Comment: @dspencer could you please let me know how to do that in this code?

Comment: @N. Arunoprayoch could you please let me know how to do that in this code?

Comment: First, strip the whitespace from your keys: `col1,col2,value = map(str.strip, line.split(","))` Then use a frozen set fort dict keys: `data[frozenset([col1,col2])].append(float(value))`

Comment: @SaraS https://repl.it/repls/BoldSmoothJavabeans